# Postgresql column from subselect does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I need to include subselect to the select statement which is common in Mysql but not work in Postgresql.
I get an error **Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "count_receipts" does not exist**

```
select "organizations".*, (
    SELECT count(*) AS count_receipts FROM companies
            JOIN receipts ON receipts.company_id = companies.id
            WHERE companies.organization_id = organizations.id
            GROUP BY companies.organization_id
) as count_receipts 
from "organizations" 
where count_receipts >= 10 
AND count_receipts <= 20
```

If I remove the where clause everything works and count_receipts column is included in result. But with where it does not work.

What is wrong with this sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the subquery as a column use it in a join :

```
SELECT o.*, count_receipts
FROM organizations o
JOIN (
  SELECT c.organization_id, count(*) AS count_receipts 
  FROM companies c
  JOIN receipts r ON r.company_id = c.id
  GROUP BY c.organization_id
) AS s on s.organization_id = o.id
WHERE count_receipts >= 10 
AND count_receipts <= 20;
```